# Why SVG base64 image all is black in IE11?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, svg, base64

Following image is ok in Chrome and Edge but why this image displays all black in IE11?

```html
<img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,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">
```

Comment: Where is the image?

Comment: Does this same image works when loaded as a standalone in IE? I am not sure they did support svg gradients set by css. You could try to set it directly as the fill attribute instead.

Comment: You code snippet is working when I try it in IE11.